# Plot data from from a file named in another file

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to write a gnuplot script that plots data from a file (no issues there), with the file name given in another file (this I need help with). I currently have the following:

```
set terminal pngcairo
set output 'interpolation.png'

plot 'output.txt' u 2:3 w lines, \
     'data_1.txt' w points
```

which works as expected. However, I generate the `output.txt` datafile that takes values from `data_X.txt` (and interpolates the data). My program reads the data file name from `stdin`, so I have an input file with all the data needed for one run. The first line of this input file is the file name of the data file for that run.

**Is there any way I can get the file name from the same input file? How?**

In other words, given a plotting script `interpolation.gpt`, a number of data files `data_X.txt` and an input file `input.txt` in which the first line names one of the `data_X.txt` files, can I make `interpolation.gpt` use the data file named in `input.txt` without having to manually edit both files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do this from within gnuplot:

```
datafile = system("head -1 output.txt")
plot 'output.txt' u 2:3 w lines, \
      datafile w points
```

Backquote substitution would have worked as well I think:

```
datafile = "`head -1 output.txt`"
```

Comment: This is actually even better! It makes it a lot more clear what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way might be to call gnuplot from another script, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

datafile=$(head -1 output.txt)

gnuplot << EOF
set terminal ...
set output ...
plot 'output.txt' u 2:3 w lines, \
     '$datafile' w points
EOF
```

Comment: This might be the only way, but I was hoping to avoid it. I've had bad experiences with the before, when trying to do more complicated using statements (e.g. `using 1:($2 > 0 ? $2 : NaN)` to plot only values larger than 0), since `$` is interpreted by the shellscript, yielding errors, instead of left to gnuplot.

Comment: The workaround to that is to escape the `$`s: `using 1:(\$2 > 0 ? \$2 : NaN)`.

Comment: Ah, well, in that case I suppose it will do!